# awk sum up values in column based on match in different column

Tags: bash, awk

I do feel it is easy but can't figure it out...
I have:

```
aaa,3
aaa,21
aaa,18
bbb,333
ccc,34
ccc,67
```

/file is sorted by 1st column/
I would like to sum up values for the same patterns

```
aaa,42
bbb,333
ccc,101
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: This answer should help you: [Sum duplicate row values with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42024367/6176817).

Comment: Yes indeed this is exactly what I needed