# How to use awk on multiple files?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, text-processing

I am using Linux. I wrote some code that looks like this:

```
for x in {10..20}:{00..59}; do awk -F';' '/'"$x"'/ {y+=$7} END {print y}' Data26092019; done
```

How to use this command on multiple files, for example: Data26092019 and Data27092019?

The files are like this:

```
09:55:13;ACSEL;4.850;16;77.60;1;1
09:55:13;ACSEL;4.850;40;194.00;2;1
09:55:13;ACSEL;4.850;465;2255.25;3;1
...
```

Output Example:

```
Data26092019 4988 10:00
Data26092019 2778 10:01
...
Data27092019 3252 10:00
Data27092019 3002 10:01
```

Maybe it should work with another for-loop or you can specify the files.

The main command is:

```
for x in {10..20}:{00..59}; do awk -F';' '/'"$x"'/ {y+=$7} END {print y}' Data26092019; done
```

It has to be executed on `Data26092019` and `Data27092019`.

Comment: `awk -F';' '/'"$x"'/ {y+=$7} END {print y}' Data26092019 Data27092019`? What do you want to do with those files?

Comment: I want that the command does it for all files seperate.

Comment: `for all files seperate` - so you want to "iterate over files" and run the command "for each file". Sure https://www.google.com/search?q=iterate+over+files+bash . Your command looks very slow - it processes the same file 120 times. It would be probably advisable and really faster to create a long awk command and process the file only once. If you just the sum of 7th column for each first column, there  is I think no need for looping over all possible values, `awk` arrays can come to the rescue.

Comment: Don't `for x in {10..20}:{00..59};`. You are running `awk` 120 times. Run it once. Your awk script really looks just like something like `awk '{ sum[$1]+=$7 } END{ foreach (i in sum) print i " " sum[i]; }`. Look at ex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024296/sum-duplicate-row-values-with-awk for some more info on such topic.

Comment: I am using this version of the command because i want the sum for all minutes seperate.

Comment: Do you want the sum per fiile, or do you want the sum accumulated over all files?

Comment: Also, the script you currently have has a big problem: If you have a line starting with `10:20:30` and a line with `23:10:20` it will count both lines for the entry `10:20`. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: I want the sum for every minute (That is because i am using a for-loop) in every file: The command should print: FILENAME, sum (y) and the minute.

Comment: If the beigining column in file is ordered, you can try find the begin and end line number for each file(e.g. awk -F ';' '$1=="10:00:00" {print NR}' Data26092019). Then print the result by sed -n '$begin,$end p' Data26092019 for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplistically, you would do the following:

```sh
for file in f1 f2 f3 f4; do
   for time in {10..20}:{00..59}; do 
      sum=$(awk -v t="${time}" -F";" '($0~"^"t){sum+=$7}END{print sum}' "$file"
      echo "$file $sum $time"
   done
done
```

This is, however, extremely slow as you will open each file multiple times when searching for the particular time-key.

I believe what you are after is this:

```
awk 'function print_summary(    h,m,key) {
        for (h=10;h<=20;++h) {
           for (m=0;m<60;++m) {
              key=sprintf("%0.2d:%0.2d",h,m)
              print fname, sum[key]+0, key
           }
        }
     }
     BEGIN{FS=";"}
     (FNR==1){if(NR>1) print_summary(); delete sum; fname=FILENAME}
     !/^..:..:../{next}
     { key=substr($0,1,5) }
     { sum[key]+=$7 }
     END { print_summary() }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

This method will skip empty files, but will report exactly what is expected.

Comment: You're so right. I knew that there has be a solution like this which is fast.

Comment: This only works for one file. If I write Data26092019 and Data27092019 the program only does it for the second file (the last given).

Comment: I run as .sh file in a terminal with the command: './Command.sh'

Comment: @User11221475 yes I see the problem, this should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** In case you want to use `END`(or don't have GNU `awk`) + you want to have sum in same order in which you are passing Input_files then try following.

***Using `END`:***

```
awk '
BEGIN{
 FS=";"
}
!filename[FILENAME]++{
  a[++count]=FILENAME
}
{
  sum[FILENAME]+=$7
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print "Sum of minute for file: " a[i] " is: " sum[a[i]]
  }
}'  Data26092019 Data27092019
```

---

---

***Using `ENDFILE`:***

Could you please try following, not tested since there are no samples provided by OP.
Needed GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {sum+=$7} ENDFILE{print "Sum of minute for file: " FILENAME " is: " sum;sum=""}' Data26092019 Data27092019
```

Comment: Where could i insert a pattern in  the second solution?

Comment: @User11221475, where you want to put or which condition you want to check? Once you clarify I could write for you

Comment: @User11221475, you can't define shell variable in awk variable you need to do like for example: `awk -v var="$shell_variable" '$0 ~ var'  file` like that.

Comment: The Code:
for Time in {10..17}:{00..59}
do
awk '
BEGIN{
 FS=";"
}
!filename[FILENAME]++{
  a[++count]=FILENAME
} 
{
  sum[FILENAME]+=$7
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print "Sum of minute for file: " a[i] " is: " sum[a[i]]
  }
}'  CTime=$Time Data26092019 Data27092019
done

I want to insert Time from the for-loop as pattern in the awk command.

Comment: @User11221475, not sure why you are running this code in for loop, it could take multiple files as input, try it in that way once?

Comment: It has to be separately for all files and I want it for every minute not for the hole file.

Comment: @User11221475, sorry I am not getting it please provide sample output with logic about what to get? I am really confused now.

Comment: The Output should be like this:

File: Data26092019 Time: 10:00 Sum: 4876

Time is the current state of the Time variable from the for-loop.
Sum is the sum of all 7nd values in the lines that are beginning with the pattern wich should be Time (/^'"$Time"'/).

Comment: This will skip empty files rather than printing them with value 0.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 how can i modify solution #1 to count unique values rather than sum them? This script counts total values in $2, but I'm aiming to capture only unique values:                                                                                                     BEGIN{
 FPAT = "[^,]*|\"[^\"]+\""
}
!filename[FILENAME]++{
  a[++count]=FILENAME
}
{
  get[FILENAME]++$2
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print "Sum of rating for file: " a[i] " is: " get[a[i]]
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
$ awk -F\; '{
    sum[FILENAME]+=$7
} 
END {
    for(f in sum)
        print f,sum[f]
}' file1 file2
```

Output with 2 copies of your sample data:

```
file1 3
file2 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works as well. I think this solution is more portable (common).

Comment: This will skip empty files rather than printing them with value 0.

Comment: Yeah, without proper sample data end expected output it's hard to say. Just took op's code to show how to output per file.

Answer (score 0):

Using gawk, you can adapt @JamesBrown answer :

```
gawk -F\; '{
    sum += $7
} 
ENDFILE {
    print FILENAME, sum
    sum=0
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: IMHO, I had already given this solution quite sometime back https://stackoverflow.com/a/58267439/5866580

Comment: This will print a null string instead of 0 if the first file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all the kindly answers. I am a newbie, i can't understand and comment all  different solutions. What helped me mostly is
the function solution from @kvantour. The code:

```
awk 'function print_summary(    h,m,key) {
        for (h=10;h<=20;++h) {
           for (m=0;m<60;++m) {
              key=sprintf("%0.2d:%0.2d",h,m)
              print fname, sum[key]+0, key
           }
        }
     }
     BEGIN{FS=";"}
     (FNR==1){if(NR>1) print_summary(); delete sum; fname=FILENAME}
     !/^..:..:../{next}
     { key=substr($0,1,5) }
     { sum[key]+=$7 }
     END { print_summary() }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Comment: Don't worry about being new to this forum. We all have been there. If you have questions, just ask them in the comments below and we will try to answer them. Also, as a new person, it is always good to take the [tour] and read [ask].